# How to make controller for Inserting one to many data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, aspnetzero

I have models that have a one-to-many relationship. I want to insert data by using a single call. Can you help me how can I write mine for the controller?
I am using **Asp.net core 3.1.** Bellow is my detail code:

**Model 1:  FacilityFixed**

```
 public class FacilityFixed : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant{
  public string Name { get; set; } 
  public ICollection<FacilityCompartment> FacilityCompartment { get; set; }
  
  }
```

**Model 2: FacilityCompartment**

```
public class FacilityCompartment : FullAuditedEntity, IMustHaveTenant
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int SensorId { get; set; }
        public FacilityFixed FacilityFixed { get; set; }
       }
```

**Controller**

```
 public async Task CreateFacilityFixed(CreateFacilityFixedInput input){
       var FacilityFixed = ObjectMapper.Map<FacilityFixed>(input);
       await _FacilityFixedRepository.InsertAsync(FacilityFixed);
        }
```

I am working in Asp.net core. Asp.Net Zero, boiler Plate.

Comment: Do you use Entity Framework or something like that? In general the ORM saves the referenced objects if they are present at save time. So you need to pass the referenced objects from client with your FacilityFixed.

Comment: Love the interface name. Next up, you should totally have an interface that describes whether the entity can have a cheeseburger...